# IBM Watson Alchemy alternative?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, alchemyapi

I've been playing around with the IBM Watson Alchemy demo and was wondering how you get it to extract a full word from a string. For example if a user were to type in "iPhone 7"... Alchemy would only pick up the "iPhone" from the string. Is it possible to get it to pick up "iPhone 7"? Or is there an alternative to Alchemy that would help to do this?

**The Demo:** https://alchemy-language-demo.mybluemix.net/

Answer (score 2):

[Watson Knowledge Studio](https://www.ibm.com/marketplace/cloud/supervised-machine-learning/us/en-us) allows for custom entity and relationship extraction in AlchemyLanguage if it's in your price range.

Targeted Emotion and Targeted Sentiment also allow you to search for specific targets in the text, so you could search for phrases like "iPhone 7" to get sentiment/emotion information. If all you are doing is checking if "iPhone 7" is in the text, these should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

A "quick fix" solution would be to build a very simple function that runs every time you detect the "iPhone" entity and looks to see if there is a digit following it.